# OdfTextDocument to DOC format byte array java

Tags: java, arrays

I was trying to generate and PDF and DOC file from an ODT Template file.

The PDF part was done like the following

```
public byte[] createPDF(ByteArrayOutputStream newOdt, String fontUrl) throws Exception {
    ByteArrayOutputStream pdf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    OdfTextDocument document = OdfTextDocument.loadDocument(new ByteArrayInputStream(newOdt.toByteArray()));
    PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create();
    if (fontUrl != null) {
        options.fontProvider(new IFontProvider() {
        ...
        }
    }
    PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, pdf, options);
    return pdf.toByteArray();
}
```

Here the parameter `newOdt` is the one where the fields are replaced with their correct values. The `fontUrl` is the path to the font format I need to use in the document. `PdfOptions` is used here to apply the font.

I tried to use the same byte array returned from the above method to generate DOC file, but the generated file was filled with random characters. Is there a way to create a similar method to generate DOC type byte array with applied font?

Comment: Which libraries do you use?